# Search and remove css properties from js cssText string

Tags: javascript, css, string

I'm looking at the `cssText` of an element and have the following string coming in:

**Input:**

```
"position: absolute; left: 33.999%; top: 835px; opacity: 1; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 0.4s; transition-delay: 0ms;"
```

I'm looking to create a function that would parse the string and return the following:

**Output:**

```
"position: absolute;  left: 33.999%;  top: 835px;"
```

EDIT:
Here's my attempt at it but what would be a more efficient way of doing this?

```
let str = 'position: absolute; left: 33.999%; top: 835px; opacity: 1; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 0.4s; transition-delay: 0ms;';
let keys = ['opacity', 'transition'];

function cleanStr(str, keys) {
    let splitStr = str.split(';');
    let matchingItems = [];

    for (let a = 0; a < splitStr.length; a++) {
        for (let b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
            if (splitStr[a].search(keys[b]) !== -1) {
                if (matchingItems.indexOf(splitStr[a]) === -1) {
                    matchingItems.push(splitStr[a]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return splitStr.filter((filteredStr) => {
        return matchingItems.indexOf(filteredStr) === -1;
    }).join('; ')
}

cleanStr(str, keys);
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGOLqZ?editors=0012).

Comment: They're being added dynamically by a 3rd party plugin during an animation but the plugin fails to remove them once the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

A O(n) solution would be to build up an object reflecting the rules, deleting the appropriate keys, and then stringifying the output:

```js
const cleanStr = (str, keys) => {
  const rules = str.split(';').reduce((rules, rule) => {
    const match = rule.match(/(\w+):\s*(\w+)/);
    if (match) {
      const [_, name, value] = match;
      rules[name] = value
    }
    return rules;
  }, {});
  keys.forEach(key => delete rules[key]);
  return Object.entries(rules).reduce((str, [key, value]) => `${str} ${key}: ${value};`, "");
};

const str = 'position: absolute; left: 33.999%; top: 835px; opacity: 1; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 0.4s; transition-delay: 0ms;';
const keys = ['opacity', 'transition'];


console.log(cleanStr(str, keys));
```

Now, to be on the safe side, you can use an ES2015 map due to the keys being potentially arbitrary (unsafe) input:

```js
const cleanStr = (str, keys) => {
  const items = str.split(';').map(rule => {
    const match = rule.match(/(\w+):\s*(\w+)/);
    return match ? [match[1], [match[2]]] : null;
  }).filter(v => !!v);
  const rules = new Map(items);
  keys.forEach(key => rules.delete(key));
  return [...rules].reduce((str, [key, value]) => `${str} ${key}: ${value};`, "");
}
const str = 'position: absolute; left: 33.999%; top: 835px; opacity: 1; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 0.4s; transition-delay: 0ms;';
const keys = ['opacity', 'transition'];
console.log(cleanStr(str, keys));
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I think both of the solutions are solid, however, the intended output is not quite there yet. I updated the question to include the output.